# Find a word that contain exactly two same characters in Linux

Tags: linux

I would like to find a words that contain exactly two same character from {a..z} and output should be like " 195 y bsygyx". That there are 195 words that contain exactly two "y" in words and followed by some example.

Comment: And where do the words comes from? Files, directories, online source? In which programming language are you trying to solve the problem? As shell script? How far did you get on your own?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the data in the desired format

```
tr ' ' '\n' <file | 
sed -nE 's/\w*(\w)\w*\1/\1\t&/p' | 
sort | 
uniq -c -w1
```

example text

> Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora inci[di]dunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

output

```
  4 a   aliquam
  8 e   beatae
  7 i   adipisci[ng]
  4 l   illo
  3 m   magnam
  2 n   nesciunt,
  7 o   commodi
  5 r   aspernatur
  1 s   perspiciatis,
  8 t   architecto
  6 u   accusantium
```

the word samples are the first ones for each letter.  For words that may have more than one pair of letters, only one of them is reported (e.g. commodi has both double o and double m; here listed for o)