# Find a word that contain exactly 2 same characters in Linux

Tags: grep

In Linux how can I find a word that contain exactly 2 same characters. Can I use grep?

Comment: post the input sample

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [your previous, closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065656/linux-find-a-word-that-contain-exactly-two-same-character). Once your question is closed, please do not post it again. You may yet acquire enough downvotes on this question to apply an automatic posting ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\w` `back-reference`.  What this does is match any two characters that are consecutive.  I beleive this only works for `[a-z,A-Z,0-9]`.

The `back-reference` creates a group from which to check the character against ... Then the `\1` checks the current character against the **previous** character.

**file.txt**

```
qwerty
qqwerty
123456
1123456
```

**command**

```
egrep '(\w)\1' file.txt
```

**output**

```
qqwerty
1123456
```